# why external audio link doesn't work with tone.js

Tags: tone.js, tonejs

I am trying to play audio samples from my host with tone.js but no sound.

I try this code from tone.js and it work :

```
const player2 = new Tone.Player("https://tonejs.github.io/audio/berklee/gong_1.mp3").toDestination();
```

when I change the link "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/berklee/gong_1.mp3" with my direct host link, no sound.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with your host, (try changing permissions on your file), try this link, it's my host, it works for me.

```
  player = new Tone.Player("https://vivo-vivendo-musica.com/sample/1_Hat.mp3").toDestination();
            // play as soon as the buffer is loaded
            player.autostart = true;
```

Comment: Thx , no it doesn't work with your link too, that's weird

Comment: @myhomestudio Can you post your code? and where are you using it, on a website or other platforms?